# How to use cut function on dates

Tags: r, date, binning

I have the following two dates:

```
dates <- c("2019-02-01",   "2019-06-30")
```

I want to create the following bins from above two dates:

```
2019-05-30, 2019-04-30, 2019-03-31, 2019-02-28
```

I used cut function along with seq,

```
dt <- as.Date(dates)

cut(seq(dt[1], dt[2], by = "month"), "month")
```

but this does not produce correct results.

Could you please shed some light on the use of cut function on dates?

Comment: `?cut.Date` will help.

Comment: lubridate has a function rollback which transforms the dates to previous month's last date.

`rollback(seq(dt[1], dt[2], by = "month"))[-1]` this will yield you following output
`[1] "2019-02-28" "2019-03-31" "2019-04-30" "2019-05-31"`

Also you can use the `sort` function to get the output in descending order

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We assume that what is wanted is all end of months between but not including the 2 dates in `dates`.  In the question dates[1] is the beginning of the month and dates[2] is the end of the month but we do not assume that although if we did it might be simplified.  We have produced descending series below but usually in R one uses ascending.

The first approach below uses a monthly sequence and cut and the second approach below uses a daily sequence.

No packages are used.

**1)** We define a first of the month function, fom, which given a Date or character date gives the Date of the first of the month using cut.  Then we calculate monthly dates between the first of the months of the two dates, convert those to end of the month and then remove any dates that are not strictly between the dates in dates.

```
fom <- function(x) as.Date(cut(as.Date(x), "month"))

s <- seq(fom(dates[2]), fom(dates[1]), "-1 month")
ss <- fom(fom(s) + 32) - 1
ss[ss > dates[1] & ss < dates[2]]
## [1] "2019-05-31" "2019-04-30" "2019-03-31" "2019-02-28"
```

**2)** Another approach is to compute a daily sequence between the two elements of dates after converting to Date class and then only keep those for which the next day has a different month and is between the dates in dates.  This does not use cut.

```
dt <- as.Date(dates)
s <- seq(dt[2], dt[1], "-1 day")
s[as.POSIXlt(s)$mon != as.POSIXlt(s+1)$mon & s > dt[1] & s < dt[2]]
## [1] "2019-05-31" "2019-04-30" "2019-03-31" "2019-02-28"
```

Comment: This is what I wanted, thank you for great explanation. Could please explain why +32 is added in this code `fom(fom(s) + 32) - 1`?

Comment: fom(s) gives the beginning of the month, adding 32 gives a date in the next month and then fom of that gives the first of that month.  Finally subtracting 1 gives the last day of s.

Comment: What happens if adding 32 gives a date 2 months away, e.g. if you start on January 31?

Comment: That's why we take the first of the month  before adding 32.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need for cut here:

```r
library(lubridate)
dates <- c("2019-02-01", "2019-06-30")
seq(min(ymd(dates)), max(ymd(dates)), by = "months") - 1
#> [1] "2019-01-31" "2019-02-28" "2019-03-31" "2019-04-30" "2019-05-31"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-11-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>